How do I use alligator (crocodile) probes?
When measuring with an oscilloscope, I use an original high frequency oscilloscope probe and a double side crocodile (alligator) clip and the results are usually very close.
Note: it is called crocodile or alligator. I'm not sure which is more correct, I'm talking about a cable with a BNC connector with a crocodile end on both + and - ends.
I'm talking about standard croc clip like the one below.

What I want to know is up to how many MHz the alligator probes are reliable. And are there other reasons or scenarios not to use alligator probes? Is it right to measure with them? What are the limits? Is there a source that can be referred to on this? I could not find a source about this, and there is no such information from any sellers.
Note: Please ask me to make corrections instead of closing the question when there is an problem in my question. When I try to create a question again, I get a similar title warning: “A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.”

The corrections must be made to the closed question to reopen it. Do not start a new question about same subject if the original was closed.

bevren15 - Hi, As explained in the above comment (and in the text box on that previous question) please edit that question to fix the problems which caused it to be voted closed- do not repost a new one. || With the improvements you made here, I expect it would be quickly reopened. || However posting a new question to bypass question closure breaks Stack Exchange etiquette, which expect people to edit a question to improve it. || If something is unclear about what to do, reply here and we'll try to explain it (or you can ask on our [meta] or in [chat]).

(continued) You said: "When I try to create a question again, I get a similar title warning: “A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.”" Yes, exactly - the site does not want you to be creating new questions which duplicate, overlap, or are otherwise substantially the same as before. One of the large parts of the Stack Exchange approach & etiquette is to edit questions to improve them. Being "closed" does not have to be a final state, for OPs who are willing to improve their question. See here for more details.

"closed" is not "deleted"; on stackexchange websites, "closed" means "waiting for improvement", and once the question is improved it will be reopened.

@Hearth, then somebody on stackexchange needs to change the language from "closed" to, say, "suspended". Otherwise the term is misleading and confusing, as practice show.

@Ale..chenski That would be a good change! But I do not have the power to enact that change.
